# Python regex with negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex

Hi with python I want to catch phone numbers in text but want to exclude the ones which are following the words Fax or fax.

I use the following regex which works if the sentence begin with Fax or fax but it doesn't work if fax is inside the sentence :

```
^(?!fax|Fax)(?:.*?)(?![-a-z])((?:[^0-9])((\+|00)33\s?|0|\(0\))[123456789][ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}[ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}[ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}[ \.\-]?[0-9]{2})(?![0-9])
```

Here a example of text I analyse :

```
text
Adresse quai du Sa fax 06 32 32 32 33 rtel – 59100 ROUBAIX| FRANCE
faTel : 0 8 99 70 1761 – Fax : 06 32 32 32 34
Mail :support@domain.com
06 32 32 32 35

Fax 06 32 32 32 36
tel 06 32 32 32 37 henrg
```

the result of my regex is :

```
Match 1
Full match  5-42    `Adresse quai du Sa fax 06 32 32 32 33`
Group 1.    27-42   ` 06 32 32 32 33`
Group 2.    28-29   `0`
Match 2
Full match  72-117  `faTel : 0 8 99 70 1761 – Fax : 06 32 32 32 34`
Group 1.    102-117 ` 06 32 32 32 34`
Group 2.    103-104 `0`
Match 3
Full match  118-157 `Mail :support@domain.com
06 32 32 32 35`
Group 1.    142-157 `
06 32 32 32 35`
Group 2.    143-144 `0`
Match 4
Full match  178-196 `tel 06 32 32 32 37`
Group 1.    181-196 ` 06 32 32 32 37`
Group 2.    182-183 `0`
```

But I don't want "06 32 32 32 34" and "06 32 32 32 33" in the result because "fax" is before...

Thanks

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want to obtain all numbers except numbers followed by Fax and fax?

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a regex that will match what you do not need but will match and *capture* what you need:

```
(?i)fax\W*\d[\s\d]*|(\d[\s\d]*\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1iBSes/1). Green highlighted items are what you need to grab. Note: the numbers you will get in Group 1 should contain at least 2 digits. Also, you may precise the patterns as per further requirements, just use the same "framework", as I tried to simplify the regex structure to show the main concept.

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `fax` - the `fax` substring
- `\W*` - any 0+ non-word chars (you may precise it to only work with spaces and colons, like `\s*(?::\s*)?`)
- `\d` - a digit
- `[\s\d]*` - 0+ whitespaces or digits
- `|` - or...
- `(\d[\s\d]*\d)` - Group 1 (the value you need)

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[\s\d]*` - 0+ whitespaces or digits
  - `\d` - a digit

In Python 2, use

```
import re
rx = r"(?i)fax\W*\d[\s\d]*|(\d[ \d]*\d)"
s ="text\nAdresse quai du Sa fax 06 32 32 32 33 rtel – 59100 ROUBAIX| FRANCE\nfaTel : 0 8 99 70 1761 – Fax : 06 32 32 32 34\nMail :support@domain.com\n06 32 32 32 35\n\nFax 06 32 32 32 36\ntel 06 32 32 32 37 henrg"
res = filter(None, re.findall(rx, s))
print(res)
# => ['59100', '0 8 99 70 1761', '06 32 32 32 35', '06 32 32 32 37']
```

See the [Python 2 demo](https://ideone.com/DHbisF)

Comment: Do you know how to match the "Par fax au 02 97 01 22 98" too? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You're using lookahead instead of lookbehind `(?<!..)`

With this regex I seem to get all the phone numbers and no fax numbers:

```
(?<!Fax |fax )((\d\d\s){5}|((\d\s){2}(\d\d\s){2}\d{4}))
```

Comment: Yes you are right! I forgot the space in the negative lookbehind. I will change my answer now!